# Improve string - prefix matching performance

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, string-comparison

I'm looking for a way to speed up my naive string matching process:

```
// Treat this as pseudo code
function find(input: string, prefixes: string[]) {
  for (let i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
    const prefix = prefixes[i];
    
    if (input.startsWith(prefix)) {
      return prefix;
    }
  }

  return null;
}

const prefixes = [ "Hey", "Hi", "Hola", ... ];
const prefix = find("Hey, I'm Michael", prefixes);
```

I've looked into some probabilistic data structures like the bloom filter but I couldn't find one that'd fit my needs. This being said, I don't actually care to get the prefix that would have matched neither do I need a 100% guarantee that a match exists. I only need to know if the input does definitely NOT contain any prefix or that it might.

I've also come across an article about a Burst Tries algorithm which as far as I could understand will serve a similar purpose. Frankly, though I'm not deep enough into algorithms to grasp the full implementation details and make sure this is what I'm looking for.

Side note:
I assume that 99.95% of the input this function will be getting is not going to match any prefix. Therefore I would like for this to be an optimization step to only process strings that will likely have a prefix I'm looking for.

Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated :3

Comment: just check 0.05% of the strings passed... however your algorithm is O(n)... sublinear algorithm usually works with sorted input

Comment: const prefix=prefixes.filter(x=>input.startsWith(x));

Comment: @SolomonPByer that even worsens the performance

Comment: how many strings are we talking already

Comment: You can add the prefixes into a trie, walk the input string until there's no match. That could be faster depending on how many elements you have.

Comment: Thanks, @AlbertoSinigaglia I could look into sorting the array first. However, I was hoping to find a way to filter out some strings first so I wouldn't have to process all of them.

Comment: I will definitely look into tries again @MinusFour ;). If there are enough prefixes this should be an improvement over my current solution.

Comment: What are the input constraints? Number of prefix strings. Maximum length of a prefix string. Number of strings to match.

Comment: The input string can be any string up to a length of 2 - 4000 characters. The prefix would usually not be any longer than 10 characters. There is no given number of strings that need to be matched. This is part of an event emitter callback that can fire up to 1000 times per second. @user3386109

Comment: One option is to create 10 bloom filters, one for each prefix length. If the result is "definitely not in set" for each prefix length, then the string doesn't match. I would structure the code so that the bloom filter is checked from within the code that's computing the hash. In other words, each of the hashes is updated with the first character from the input, and the Bloom-length-1 filter is checked. Add a character, check Bloom-length-2, etc. Most of the time, the code will have to finish the hashes all the way out to 10 characters, to prove that the string doesn't match.

Comment: The question is whether you get new prefixes every time (what the function suggests) or are they rarely changing, so you could do some precalculation on them. In this case I would go with MinusFour suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the prefixes are known in advance and can be preprocessed, you might try a trie. Especially if they are going to be as short as 10 characters. That would mean each check is on the order of 10 comparisons. Not sure how much better one could do.

```js
function buildTrie(trie, words){
  for (let word of words){
    let _trie = trie;

    for (let i=0; i<word.length; i++){
      const letter = word[i];
      _trie[letter] = _trie[letter] || {};

      if (i == word.length - 1)
        _trie[letter]['leaf'] = true;

      _trie = _trie[letter];
    }
  }

  return trie;
}


function find(trie, str, i=0){
  const letter = str[i];
  
  if (!trie[letter])
    return false;
    
  if (trie[letter]['leaf'])
    return true;
    
  return find(trie[letter], str, i + 1);
}


const prefixes = [ "Hey", "Heya", "Hi", "Hola"];
const trie = buildTrie({}, prefixes)

console.log(trie)

console.log(find(trie, "Hey, I'm Michael"));
console.log(find(trie, "Heuy, I'm Michael"));
```

Answer (score 2):

This has no logical difference from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68900295/1243641) by גלעד ברקן, but it displays working with a trie in a quite different code style.  (It also uses `$` instead of `leaf` as a terminator; a Symbol would be a good alternative.)

```js
const trie = (words) => 
  words .reduce (insertWord, {}) 
const insertWord = (trie, [c, ...cs]) => 
  c ? {...trie, [c]: insertWord (trie [c] || {}, cs)} : {...trie, $: 1}
const hasPrefix = (trie) => ([c, ...cs]) =>
  '$' in trie ? true : c ? c in trie && hasPrefix (trie [c]) (cs) : true
const testPrefixes = (prefixes) => 
  hasPrefix (trie (prefixes))

const hasGreeting = testPrefixes (["Hey", "Hi", "Hola", "Howdy"])

console .log (hasGreeting ("Hey, I'm Michael"))
console .log (hasGreeting ("Hello, Michael. I'm Michelle"))

console .log (trie ((["Hey", "Hi", "Hola", "Howdy"])))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

`testPrefixes` accepts a list of prefixes and returns a function that will report on whether a string starts with one of those prefixes.  It does this by creating a trie and partially applying it to `hasPrefix`.  Internally, the trie is built by folding `insertWord` over an initial empty object.

Of course this only makes sense if your use-case has prefixes that are reused for multiple calls.  If not, I see little better than `const testPrefixes = (prefixes) => (word) => prefixes .some ((pfx) => word .startsWith (pfx))`

Answer (score 0):

For search for a lot of possible substrings in the string, you can use idea from [Rabin-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) algorithm.

In my program [Banmoron](https://medium.com/@emer.tech/banmoron-9898fe8831a8) I used this algorithm for select malicious requests by search substring. See sources on [github](https://github.com/emercoin/BanMoron).

Answer (score -1):

Edit: It makes sense that startsWith is faster than indexOf, I struggle to find benchmarks comparing the two, the one I did find depends on browser speed and chrome runs indexOf faster than startsWith, I would love to know more on this. Below is the original answer:

I have taken a lot to .indexOf recently for most of these cases. The performance, from what I have read up, is better than most loop cases and allows for easy use, here is an example of two functions:

1. findOne: Returns the first entry that is found (breaks the loop which can increase performance).
2. findAll: Loops through all prefixes and returns an array of the
   found prefixes

If you are specifically looking for prefixes (thus the index value is equal to 0, just change the function to represent it with

```
input.indexOf(prefixes[i]) === 0
```

instead of

```
input.indexOf(prefixes[i]) >= 0
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
const exampleString = "Hello, I am Michael, bey";
const examplePrefixes = ["Hello", "Holla", "bey"];

function findOne(input, prefixes) {
  // Loop through prefixes to test if is in the string
  for (let i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
    // If the prefix does not exist in the string it returns a value of -1
    if (input.indexOf(prefixes[i]) >= 0) {
      // Retrun the prefix value if it is found
      return prefixes[i];
    }
  }
  // Return null if nothing is found
  return null
}

function findAll(input, prefixes) {
  // Initialize return array
  let retArr = [];
  // Loop through prefixes to test if is in the string
  for (let i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
    // If the prefix does not exist in the string it returns a value of -1
    if (input.indexOf(prefixes[i]) >= 0) {
      // If the prefix exists, push it onto the return array
      retArr.push(prefixes[i]);
    }
  }
  // return the array after looping through each prefix
  return retArr.length !==0 ?  retArr :  null
}

let value1 = findOne(exampleString, examplePrefixes);
let value2 = findAll(exampleString, examplePrefixes);

console.log(value1); // Hello
console.log(value2); // [ 'Hello', 'bey' ]
```

Comment: Using `indexOf` is way worse than using `startsWith`

Comment: I think it depends on what browser you use but these benchmarks say differently-

https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/216404

Comment: You can run the benchmark on your own too https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/4797/1/js-regex-vs-startswith-vs-indexof

Comment: Safari is slower than Chrome, but the difference in chrome is night and day compared to any other browser

https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/216406

Comment: This appears to be a [meaningless microbenchmark](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html). I'm pretty certain `indexOf` appears to be so fast is because it is optimised away entirely, as the compiler realises its result isn't used anywhere.